# Can't access Thomson modem interface anymore

Tags: networking, router, modem

I used to be able to access the web interface of my Thomson DWG849 router/modem through both 192.168.100.1 and 192.168.87.1, but now, suddenly, I can't anymore.

I have tried resetting the router without any luck.

My internet still works, though, and IP-config still say that the default gateway is 192.168.87.1.

Any ideas on what has happened and how to fix it?

Comment: What happens when you go to 192.168.87.1 exactly? Have you tried to just reboot the router?

Comment: I get error "101" in Chrome: "Connection was reset".
Similar error pages in IE and Firefox.

Yes, I tried restarting it too. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you reset the router, its IP configuration will revert to factory defaults. What was the factory default IP of your router. Usually it is 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, 192.168.1.254 etc.

Try both http://192.168.x.x
and 
https://192.168.x.x

Comment: It was 192.168.87.1 by default when I got it from my provider, Stofanet in Denmark.

Comment: This might help http://maxqubit.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/error-101-neterr_connection_reset-the-connection-was-reset/

Answer (score 0):

Try a hard 30/30/30 reset.

hold down the reset button for 30 seconds, pull the power (with the reset button still depressed) for another 30 and then plug in the adapter with the reset button held for another 30.

Then try accessing the router via the default login.

I recently had a linksys router that refused to reset until I did this.